# Laravel 5 Openshift Database not connecting

Tags: laravel-5, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I am setting up a Laravel 5 openshift application but every time i had the database code in project it says whoops something missing. I have added the environment in .env as in my database credential an still no success. I am wondering what may be the cause of this since I followed all instruction the website is working but only if I omit my database code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get your database working for local or remote development? The `.env` file in the root directory is for local development, while the `.openshift/.env` file is for remote development. If you're using an standard OpenShift database (such as MySQL or PostgreSQL), you shouldn't need to make any configuration changes to get the database working. It's already configured via environment variables.

Comment: Okay if its already configured oh an yes I am using a standard openshift Db so am wondering why am getting "whoops something is wrong" for if its already configured an I created records in the db openshift already gave why is not picking up from my code if I remove my db code it shows the website but if I add my model an then allow the controller to spit it to the view i get that message what could be that cause?

Comment: With your info am assuming I dont need to config my Db .env file it automatically picks up the db so my code i have that requesting data from say a table call users, it should just spit that name to the view.